# SSRS: Fixed headers while scrolling

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Before you accuse me of dup posting, trust me, I'm not.

I have an issue with keeping headers visible while scrolling. It doesn't work. I deploy the project, and no browser (or version therof) will fix the accursed header.

I have a report with 2x Tablix, one above the other. I need the header row of the second tablix to remain fixed. The header row isn't actually the first row, so I set the Static group to `FixedData=True`.

The tablix has been set to `KeepTogether=True`, resulting in the 15+ pages appearing as one long page.

I have set Tablix `FixedColumnHeaders=False` and `FixedRowHeaders=False` (although I have tried with `=True` with the same result: no fixed header.

Browsers used: Chrome, Firefox, IE11/10/9/8

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by changing the `static` components of `Row Groups` to `FixedData=True`.

[image]

Comment: I did that ("so I set the Static group to FixedData=True")

Comment: You get the issue locally or after deployment? I did a test in my local, it worked for 2 tablix.

Comment: Appears to affect both

Comment: I missed one of the static groups... solved, thanks.